# Staff rank using gamemode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

On my small minecraft server, the MITs (Mod in Training) have access to /gamemode /gm(s or c) when they don't have a permission node for it. I don't want the MIT rank to have access to the game mode changing commands.

Comment: Is this a bukkit server?

Comment: post your config, either into a pastebin link or other way (if not here directly with ctrl + k) so we can see.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure they aren't OPed or have the * permission.

If using PEX, I personally add the permission, but prefix it with a '-' meaning that it prevents the node from coming into use regardless of inheritance.

In your case, if using Essentials, you would do:
/pex   add -essentials.gamemode.*
/pex   add -essentials.gamemode
And if your not using Essentials, then here is what you'd do:
/pex   add -bukkit.command.gamemode

Answer (score 1):

you could make a scoreboard clock that automaticly reverts the gamemode change:

`/scoreboard objectives add mode dummy`

`/scoreboard players set [MITsurvival] mode 0`

`/scoreboard players set [MITcreative] mode 1`

on a clock:

`/gamemode s @a[m=!s,score_mode=0]`

`/gamemode c @a[m=!s,score_mode_min=1]`

the only problem I see is that someone in the know of how it works could change their scoreboard value, or simply destroy the clock. If you can find a good workaround for both of these, this should be foolproof